# Constrain values in a table using values of a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So I have two tables:

```
Requests
--------
Id
RequestSchemeId
ReceivedByUserId

ForwardedRequests
-----------------
Id
RequestId (FK to Id column of Requests Table)
ForwardedToUserId
```

Now one business rule says that a user can receive only one Request for a particular RequestScheme. So I created a UniqueKey constraint for RequestSchemeId+ReceivedByUserId. Which should solve my problem

The second business rule is that request can be forwarded to another user only if forwarded user does not already have a forwarded request under the same scheme from any other user.

The solution I can think of is a RequestSchemeId column in the ForwardedRequests table which is just a copy of the value in the related row of the Requests table and then add a unique constraint on ForwardedToUserId+RequestSchemeId.

Is this the correct way of doing it? If not what is?

How do I get value of the RequestSchemeId from Requests to ForwardedRequests when a new row is created in the latter? UDF is something I looked at but it seemed to have some gotchas and I need the standard/recommended way of doing this not something flaky.

Comment: Do ForwardedRequests have any additional attributes to non forwarded Requests (apart from the `ForwardedToUserId` column?) Also why does `ForwardedRequests` have an `Id` column as opposed to having a PK of  `RequestId`? And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: "Do ForwardedRequests have any additional attributes to non forwarded Requests?" Yes. "Why does ForwardedRequests have an Id?" The same request can be forwarded to multiple users. SQL 2008

Comment: Just to avoid confusion. There is much more to the tables than what is in the question. Even table names are different. I've just simplified it to explain the problem and remove the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique index on a view to enforce this constraint. Example below.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Requests 
  ( 
     Id               INT PRIMARY KEY, 
     RequestSchemeId  INT, 
     ReceivedByUserId INT, 
     UNIQUE (RequestSchemeId, ReceivedByUserId) 
  ) 

CREATE TABLE dbo.ForwardedRequests 
  ( 
     Id                INT PRIMARY KEY, 
     RequestId         INT REFERENCES Requests(Id), 
     ForwardedToUserId INT 
  ) 

GO 

CREATE VIEW dbo.ForwardedUserRequestSchemes 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
  SELECT ForwardedToUserId, 
         RequestSchemeId 
  FROM   dbo.ForwardedRequests FR 
         JOIN dbo.Requests R 
           ON R.Id = FR.RequestId 

GO 

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix 
  ON dbo.ForwardedUserRequestSchemes(ForwardedToUserId, RequestSchemeId)
```

Comment: This works great! Can I also 'somehow' add a constraint to the view which says ReceivedByUserId != ForwardedToUserId? I don't need a sample, I think I understand views in general now, just the approach. Constraints aren't allowed in Views it seems.

Comment: @NVM - Yep. Can't add a constraint to a view so not a "clean" way of extending it do that. You could prevent such records being added by adding to the view an additional column `,1/(ForwardedToUserId - ReceivedByUserId) AS FailIfSame` which would raise a `Divide by zero error` exception if the two values are the same.

Comment: Heh. That would be really ugly. Thanks.

Comment: @NVM - And thought of another way that also won't win any beauty contests!