# Alternative to check constraints in Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have two tables:

```
Requests
--------
Id
RequestSchemeId
ReceivedByUserId

ForwardedRequests
-----------------
Id
RequestId (FK to Id column of Requests Table)
ForwardedToUserId
```

and one view

```
ForwardedRequestsInRequestSchemes
---------------------------------
Requests.RequestSchemeId
Requests.ReceivedByUserId
ForwardedRequests.ForwardedToUserId
```

What's the standard/recommended way of adding a constraint *equivalent* to `Requests.ReceivedByUserId != ForwardedRequests.ForwardedToUserId` in the view?

I know check constraints are not allowed in views. Using SQL Server 2008.

EDIT:

This is a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749902/constrain-values-in-a-table-using-values-of-a-column-in-another-table).

Business rules:

1. The same request can be forwarded to multiple users. Hence the Id column in the ForwardedRequests table.
2. A user can receive only one Request for a particular RequestScheme. So I created a UniqueKey constraint for RequestSchemeId+ReceivedByUserId in the Requests table.
3. The request can be forwarded to another user only if forwarded user does not already have a forwarded request under the same scheme from any other user. So as Martin suggested in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749902/constrain-values-in-a-table-using-values-of-a-column-in-another-table), I created a view from the two tables and added a unique constraint on Requests.RequestSchemeId+ForwardedRequests.ForwardedToUserId.
4. The business rule this question is about, is that the receiver of the request cannot forward it to himself/herself.

Comment: Why don't you use `WHERE Requests.ReceivedByUserId <> ForwardedRequests.ReceivedByUserId` ?

Comment: @Kaf - That won't help. [The additional context of the question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9749902/73226)

Comment: Should a request be allowed to be forwarded to a person and later forwarded back to any of the people who'd already received it? (Or maybe I should first ask whether a request can be forwarded multiple times...)

Comment: Please have a look at the linked question which has the business rules you have asked about. Typing in from a mobile device, will update the question once my connection is back....

Comment: @AndriyM I think I now understand your question. No, a user who has received a request under a particular scheme cannot be forwarded back a request in the same scheme. I guess what you are getting at is pull Id and UserId from both the tables and combine the results and then put a unique constraint on Id+UserId. I think that will solve the problem although I would still like to know how to do what I've asked(correctly) because it also applies to other tables.

Comment: @NVM: Yes, that was what I was thinking at the time, putting a constraint on the union of the two tables, but then I remembered (and verified myself [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx "Creating Indexed Views")) that an indexed view must not have, among other things, a UNION operator. Pity, it would have simplified the job so much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways of getting SQL Server to enforce this for you. Both pretty hacky though so interested to see any other approaches.

1) You could add to the indexed view `ForwardedRequestsInRequestSchemes` an additional column `1/(ForwardedToUserId - ReceivedByUserId) AS FailIfSame` which would raise a `Divide by zero error` if the two values are the same. This does mean that you end up storing a redundant column in the indexed view though.

2) You could create a new view that returns any such rows cross joined onto a two row table then define a unique constraint on that view. This view will always be empty.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoRows(C INT) INSERT INTO dbo.TwoRows VALUES(1),(1)

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.FailIfForwardedUserEqualToReceivedByUser
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
  SELECT 1 AS C
  FROM   dbo.ForwardedRequests FR 
         INNER JOIN dbo.Requests R 
           ON R.Id = FR.RequestId AND R.ReceivedByUserId = FR.ForwardedToUserId
         CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoRows

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON 
     dbo.FailIfForwardedUserEqualToReceivedByUser(C)
```

Comment: AFAIK cross joins are not allowed in indexable views.

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin - Yes they are. I've tested this and both work fine in getting SQL Server to enforce the requirement.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think this can be solved more elegantly by using a [filtered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) in SQL 2008

Comment: @NVM - I'm aware of filtered indexes but can't see how this would help with the cross table requirement? Feel free to add an answer expanding on this!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to disallow `update, insert, delete` rights on the tables, and enforce the business requirement using a stored procedure.  For example,

```
create procedure dbo.AddRequestForward(
    @requestId int
,   @forwardedToUserId int)
as
insert  ForwardedRequests
        (ForwardedRequests, ForwardedRequests)
select  @requestId
,       @forwardedToUserId
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Requests
        where   Id = @requestId
                and @forwardedToUserId = @forwardedToUserId
        )

if @@rowcount = 0
    return -1 -- Forwarded and Received identical user
return 1 -- Success
go
```

Comment: Without additional locking hints this has race conditions (which is why it is generally better to get SQL Server to enforce these constraints).

Comment: @MartinSmith: As long as the question doesn't specify heavy concurrent traffic, I think this is safe enough

Comment: @Andomar "Safe Enough" sounds scary. I am new to database programming but I think it would be wise to use Martin's *ugly* approach over this as it will atleast never go wrong.

Comment: Maybe this question is old but I want to explain my downvote: putting stored procedure interfaces around your low level data manipulation not only leads to race conditions as mentioned, but often becomes a performance killer. Off-loading to the relational DB engine (e.g. via constraints) is usually preferable whenever available.